# How to call a function inside another function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to call a function inside another function but the result I'm getting is 0

[image]

```
Function DepositRate(Deposit):
    If Deposit > 100000 Then
        Rtaxa = 0.078
    ElseIf Deposit <= 100000 And Deposit > 10000 Then
        Rtaxa = 0.073
    ElseIf Deposit <= 10000 And Deposit > 1000 Then
        Rtaxa = 0.063
    ElseIf Deposit <= 1000 And Deposit > 0 Then
        Rtaxa = 0.055
    Else
        Rtaxa = "Negative Value"
    End If
    
    DepositRate = Rtaxa
        
End Function

Function NewDFV(Value, Year):
    Call DepositRate(Value)
    ValorFuturo = Deposit * (1 + Rtaxa) ^ (Year)
    NewDFV = ValorFuturo
    
End Function
```

So,  Where I'm doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

### A Function Calling a Function

- Note that both functions can be used as UDF's. If you don't want the first function to appear in the functions list, use `Private Function GetDepositrate(...)...` while keeping both functions in the same module. The function will still be available just not listed.

```vb
Option Explicit

Function GetDepositrate(ByVal Deposit As Double) As Double
    
    Dim RTaxa As Double
    
    If Deposit > 100000 Then
        RTaxa = 0.078
    ElseIf Deposit > 10000 Then
        RTaxa = 0.073
    ElseIf Deposit > 1000 Then
        RTaxa = 0.063
    ElseIf Deposit > 0 Then
        RTaxa = 0.055
    Else
        ' Negative Value - do nothing
    End If
    
    GetDepositrate = RTaxa

End Function

Function NewDFV(ByVal Deposit As Double, ByVal Year As Long) As Double
    
    Dim RTaxa As Double: RTaxa = GetDepositrate(Deposit)
    
    NewDFV = Deposit * (1 + RTaxa) ^ (Year)

End Function
```

Comment: @braX, you are advised to use this example by @VBasic2008 for better practice: add `Option Explicit`, and declare (DIM) your variables with data types as you would expect them. You might like to declare them `as variant` if you expect to return different types (for example, if you want to return an error condition as #NA).

Answer (score 1):

Unless `Rtaxa` is declared as a module or global variable, you will need to assign the return value of `DepositRate` to `Rtaxa` within function `NewDFV`

```
Function NewDFV(Value, Year)
    Dim Rtaxa As Variant
    Rtaxa  = DepositRate(Value)
    ValorFuturo = Deposit * (1 + Rtaxa) ^ (Year)
    NewDFV = ValorFuturo
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function with a `=NewDVF(D1;D2)` it should be  =NewDVF(D1, D2) (must be comma, not semicolon)

Also you are calling the DepositRate function with CALL (normally reserved for Subs), and discarding its result; you should assign it to something.

Also you should use the Value (not the Deposit) to make the final calculation.

```
Function DepositRate(Deposit):
    If Deposit > 100000 Then
        Rtaxa = 0.078
    ElseIf Deposit <= 100000 And Deposit > 10000 Then
        Rtaxa = 0.073
    ElseIf Deposit <= 10000 And Deposit > 1000 Then
        Rtaxa = 0.063
    ElseIf Deposit <= 1000 And Deposit > 0 Then
        Rtaxa = 0.055
    Else
        Rtaxa = "Negative Value"
    End If
    
    DepositRate = Rtaxa
        
End Function

Function NewDFV(Value, Year):
    Rtaxa = DepositRate(Value)
    ValorFuturo = Value * (1 + Rtaxa) ^ (Year)
    NewDFV = ValorFuturo
    
End Function
```